# Toad problems with comments

Tags: oracle, vpn, toad

I have problems with the comments in Toad.

I copied a few lines of code from the notepad to Toad and generate strange characters.

**UPDATE:** I got this problem while working from a remote desktop via a VPN.

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Contact Toad support? At what they charge for their product, tech support should be outstanding.

Comment: Use text pad. Or better yet use Toad editor itself. Or save the file as .sql and then open it in toad using File > Open.

Comment: This works fine for me using Windows 7 Notepad and Toad 6.0

Comment: In those cases i do is go to the end of comment and give a blank and shows the full comment.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

From the name of the notepad file I understand that your native language is French.
You simply saved the txt file in Encode that not work on suitable to Toad fully.
Simply save the notepad in regular encode and it will work fine (this is at least what I did to solve that problem)

Comment: that's a funny comment ^^ Bloc de notas, edición, Ver, ayuda... French??

Comment: More seriously, I suspect there's nothing to do with this at all. I'm using my OS in spanish and toad works very well with copy pasting.

Comment: Thanks @The-Blad3r, but my native lenguage is Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer, it is an encoding issue with languages when working over vpn. Apparently changing the keyboard layout should fix this as well.

https://superuser.com/questions/1254070/encoding-problems-when-copy-pasting-from-a-remote-desktop-session

Comment: On a side note, I really think this man could use notepad++. For all I know, using a better text editor might just as well fix this issue since both examples I have seen site issues with basic notepad.